# Second Derivative of Polar Coordinate Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert the following equation to polar coordinates:
$$
x'' - x' + x^2x'+x'^3 + x =0
$$

I know that $x' = r'\cos(\theta)-r\theta \sin(\theta)$, however I am not too sure where to go from here?

I know it should be $x'' = \frac{d}{dt}(r'\cos(\theta)-r\theta \sin(\theta))$ but not entirely sure how to evaluate this.

Thanks.

Comment: it does look like in your ODE that $=$ is missing. Also are you assuming $x = x(r,\theta)$ or are you transforming an ODE in $(x,y)$ to one in $(r,\theta)$?

Comment: ah sorry! Yeah it is suppose to be = 0. Shall make the change now. The transform is suppose to be (r,$\theta$)

Comment: Your equation does not involve $y$. It is a 1-dimensional equation. But polar coordinates are used to describe a 2-dimensional space. How does this even make sense? Is part of the problem missing?

Comment: You can still solve it by introducing a new variable any converting it according if you let $y=\dot{x}$

Answer (score 1):

As you did, I'll denote with a prime the time derivative. Although you did not mention it explicitly, I assume that you are considering
$$x = r\cos\theta\,.$$
Then everything is just a matter of differentiating compositions and products of functions.

You have
$$x' = (r\cos\theta)' = r'\cos\theta + r(\cos\theta)' = r'\cos\theta -r\theta'\sin\theta\,.$$
Then
$$(r'\cos\theta)' = r''\cos\theta + r'(\cos\theta)' = r''\cos\theta -r'\theta'\sin\theta$$
and
$$(r\theta'\sin\theta)' = r'\theta'\sin\theta + r\theta''\sin\theta + r\theta'(\sin\theta)' = r'\theta'\sin\theta + r\theta''\sin\theta + r(\theta')^2\cos\theta\,.$$
Putting all together you have
$$x'' = r''\cos\theta -2r'\theta'\sin\theta -r\theta''\sin\theta -r(\theta')^2\cos\theta\,.$$
Now you have the expressions for $x''$ and $x'$ and you have just to plug them in your initial ODE.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to polar coordinates, that is also more adapted to the equation
$$
x''+(x^2+x'^2-1)x'+x=0,
$$
is to compute the radius and angle as polar coordinates of the pair $(x,y)=(x,x')$, so that $x=r\cosθ$, $y=x'=r\sinθ$ purely from the geometry. Then
\begin{alignat}{3}
rr'&=xx'+yy'&&=(x''+x)x'\\
r^2θ'&=xy'-x'y&&=-r^2+x(x''+x)\\
\end{alignat}
and insert that $x''+x=(1-r^2)x'$, so that you end up with
\begin{alignat}{3}
r'&=&r(1-r^2)\sin^2θ&=\frac12r(1-r^2)(1-\cos(2θ))\\
θ'&=&-1+(1-r^2)\sinθ\cosθ&=-1+\frac12(1-r^2)\sin(2θ)
\end{alignat}
On average, this gives a clockwise rotation with constant speed $1$, the radius moving towards $r=1$ from all points except $r=0$.

Comment: Is this not more complex since you are dealing with squaring trig identities then? How would you go about using this to solve the given question? Thanks, i'm interested in this method.

Comment: For example, I have the following: $\dot{x} = y$ and so we get $\dot{y} = \dot{r}sin(\theta) + \dot{\theta}rcos(\theta)$ which means we now have, $\dot{r}cos(\theta)-\dot{\theta}sin(\theta) = (1-r^2)rcos(\theta)-rsin(\theta)$ and $\dot{r}sin(\theta) + \dot{\theta}rcos(\theta) = rcos(\theta) + (1-r^2)sin(\theta)$

Comment: Plugging these into the equation, I get $\frac{1}{r}\dot{r}cos(\theta)-\dot{\theta}sin(\theta)=(1-r^2)-sin(\theta)$ and for the other equation I get, $\frac{1}{r}(\dot{r}sin(\theta)+\dot{\theta}cos(\theta))=cos(\theta) + (1-r^2)sin(\theta)$. However, when I use the matrix, these equations don't equal each other out, so I think I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Use the geometric form of $x'$, not the derivative of the parametrization of $x$. The resulting formulas are short and give a clear picture, especially in the time average.